# How to create a C# .Net Core application without a console on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, window, glfw

I'm creating a Vulkan graphics engine in C# (.Net Core) using GLFW to create a window. Obviously I don't want to force the end user to use a console just to run my application.

I know on Windows I could just create the project as a windows application, but how would I do this on Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same for what you're using, but with my .NET Core 3.0 app using Avalonia UI, I don't have to do anything special. If I double-click the executable in the file browser, it just runs -- no console window appears. If I run it from the terminal, it will block unless I run it using `./program &` to detach.

Comment: Interesting, mine too seems to run from the file system but it instantly closes after I click on it.

Answer (score -2):

The application build using .NET Core should run on Windows and Linux.

One of the [characteristics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/about) of .NET Core is being able to run the same code on different operating systems so what's build on Windows should run on Linux.

[About .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/about) is explicity about this:

> Cross-platform: Runs on Windows, macOS, and Linux operating systems.

---

[`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22) documentation contains the prepacked templates for .NET Core.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How does it not? .NET Core is for building cross-platform apps, so what the OP builds for Windows will run on Linux.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to build a cross platform app; he's asking what needs to be done to allow users to run his app on Linux without using the console, since it's a GUI app. It seems to come from the fact that on Windows you have to use `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` to prevent the console window from showing, so he is assuming there is something similar with Linux.

Comment: .NET Core 3.0 supports Winforms and WPF applications, which you aren't able to run on other than Windows operation systems.

Comment: They are some other cross-platform GUI framework . Like Uno or Avalonia